# Proving $f$ as a function of $x^2 + y^2 + z^2$ under coordinate transformation and symmetry

Tags: linear-algebra, coordinate-systems

In the vicinity of a point on a 3-dimensional Riemannian manifold, let's consider a coordinate system $(x_1, x_2, x_3)$, where the metric tensor (or line element) is expressed in the following form.

\begin{equation*}
ds^2=f(x_1,x_2,x_3)(d{x_1}^2+d{x_2}^2+d{x_3}^2).
\end{equation*}

$A$ is a $3 \times 3$ rotation matrix.
The coordinate transformation is defined as follows.
\begin{equation*}
\begin{pmatrix}
y_1 \\
y_2 \\
y_3 \\
\end{pmatrix}
=A
\begin{pmatrix}
x_1 \\
x_2 \\
x_3 \\
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{equation*}

Then, for any $A$, the component of this metric tensor is preserved.
\begin{equation*}
ds^2=f(x_1,x_2,x_3)(d{y_1}^2+d{y_2}^2+d{y_3}^2).
\end{equation*}
Therefore, when the manifold is spherically symmetric,
\begin{equation*}
f(y_1,y_2,y_3)=f(x_1,x_2,x_3).
\end{equation*}
In this case, just like in Euclidean space, I think that $f(x, y, z)$ becomes a function of $x^2 + y^2 + z^2$.
Can you prove it?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen why? It is assumed to be invariant under all rotations, so indeed it is a radial function.

Comment: In Euclidean space, it may seem obvious, but a mathematical proof is still required. In general manifolds, the very notion of rotation is not even clear.